# Upper bound on KL divergence for multinomial distributions

Tags: multinomial-distribution, information-theory, kullback-leibler

Suppose $\mathbb{P}$ is Multinomial$(1; p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_L)$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ is Multinomial$(1; q_1, q_2, \ldots, q_L)$. Assume that the difference between the probability masses are bounded, i.e. $$\max_{l = 1, \ldots, L} |p_l - q_l| < t$$ for some $0 < t < 1$. Can we bound the KL divergence $D(\mathbb{P}, \mathbb{Q})$ by some polynomial of $t$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression you gave is one expression of [total variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures). This, and KL divergence are both examples of a broader notion of distance on probability distributions known as [$f$-divergences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-divergence). A plot showing admissible values of two $f$-divergences is known as their joint range. See [these lecture notes](http://people.lids.mit.edu/yp/homepage/data/LN_fdiv.pdf) for more on that and relevant lemmas. While there are [tight lower bounds of KL divergence](http://web.math.ku.dk/%7E/topsoe/af+ph+ft.pdf) (and [arbitrary](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0906.1244.pdf) $f$-divergences) in terms of total variation alone, it seems information about $\alpha_Q=\underset{i}{\min} q_i$ is necessary to do the reverse. The [reverse Pinsker inquality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinsker%27s_inequality#Inverse_problem) is a pretty widely known expression of this sort.

$\frac{1}{2} D_{\mathrm{KL}}(P\|Q) \le \frac{1}{\alpha_Q} t^2$

While there appear to be refinements of the reversed Pinsker inequality floating around, I can't say authoritatively what the tightest bound is these days.

Comment: Thank you Alex!